# Mostrar datos de python en una tabla

Tags: python, tablas

tengo el siguiente código que toma los datos de una web de loterías y los muestra en otra web, funciona bien. El problema es al momento de presentar los datos que no se como ponerlos en celdas (filas y columnas).

En la web me los muestra asi:

[image]

Lo que me gustaría realmente es que se muestre en el siguiente formato, por poner un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El script esta hecho en Python y la web la estoy montando en PHP.

```
mport requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
from tabulate import tabulate, tabulate_formats

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
                  "Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://chancescolombia.com/"

respuesta = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

soup=BeautifulSoup(respuesta.text, "html.parser")

contenedor_de_loterias = soup.find(class_="col-12 col-games")

lista_de_loterias = contenedor_de_loterias.find_all(class_="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12")

for loteria in lista_de_loterias:
    nombre_loteria = loteria.find(class_="col-game").text
    numero_loteria = loteria.find(class_="game-scores").text

    # Limpieza de datos

    nombre_loteria = nombre_loteria.replace("\r","").strip()
    numero_loteria = numero_loteria.replace("\r", "").replace(" ", "").strip()

    # Correcion uso de tildes

    nombre=nombre_loteria.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    numero=numero_loteria.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    
    # Creando tabla

    tabla= [nombre,"->",numero]

    print(tabulate(tabla))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunos problemas con el código y los datos.

La variable `numero` contiene múltiples `\n`, que deben ser reemplazados por espacio. Además, hay que formar la tabla completa antes de imprimirla

```
# Creando tabla
numero = numero.replace("\n", " ")
tabla.append([nombre, "->", numero])
```

Dentro del ciclo iremos simplemente agregando lineas a la tabla; una vez finalizado, imprimimos la tabla completa.

#### Demo

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
                  "Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://chancescolombia.com/"

respuesta = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(respuesta.text, "html.parser")

contenedor_de_loterias = soup.find(class_="col-12 col-games")

lista_de_loterias = contenedor_de_loterias.find_all(class_="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12")

tabla = []
for loteria in lista_de_loterias:
    nombre_loteria = loteria.find(class_="col-game").text
    numero_loteria = loteria.find(class_="game-scores").text

    # Limpieza de datos

    nombre_loteria = nombre_loteria.replace("\r", "").strip()
    numero_loteria = numero_loteria.replace("\r", "").replace(" ", "").strip()

    # Correcion uso de tildes

    nombre = nombre_loteria.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    numero = numero_loteria.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

    # Creando tabla
    numero = numero.replace("\n", " ")
    tabla.append([nombre, "->", numero])
    #print(tabla)

print(tabulate(tabla))
```

con esta entrada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

produce:

```
--------------------  --  -----------------
Super Astro Luna      ->  5  6  6  0  Libra
La Caribea Noche      ->  4  9  6  2
Sinuano Noche         ->  4  8  3  2
La Culona Noche       ->  1  9  7  1
Motiln Noche          ->  9  3  2  1
Cafeterito Noche      ->  7  9  3  2
Chontico Noche        ->  0  8  6  8
Pick 4 Noche          ->  0  6  8  0  1
Fantstica Noche       ->  8  2  5  0
Paisita Noche         ->  6  1  9  1
Antioqueita Tarde 2   ->  1  0  8  2
Dorado Tarde          ->  4  6  9  0
Motiln Tarde          ->  3  6  0  1
La Caribea Da         ->  5  7  2  9
Sinuano Da            ->  6  6  8  8
La Culona Da          ->  3  9  8  6
Super Astrol Sol      ->  4  5  2  3  Cncer
Pijao de Oro          ->  5  2  0  2
Paisita Da            ->  2  6  9  4
El Samn de la Suerte  ->  0  9  3  0
Chontico Da           ->  2  9  4  6
Fantstica Da          ->  2  7  8  9
Pick 4 Da             ->  1  1  4  1  2
Cafeterito Tarde      ->  5  5  0  0
Dorado Maana          ->  9  3  4  3
Antioqueita Da        ->  5  2  2  8
--------------------  --  -----------------
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Hola, primero quiero darte las gracias a funcionado en consola ya me los muestra perfectos. Muchísimas gracias. En la web aun me los agrupa todos, pero supongo que es cosa del PHP. Muchas gracias